# How can we change each bar in bar chart in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have a bar chart in Matlab. and I want to change every 6 bar to the same color. For example, the first 6 of them to the red, the second 6 of them to the blue, the third 6 of them to green, and the fourth 6 of them to black. Here is my code:
data_forest=xlsread('for.xlsx');

data_forest=data_forest';

x=[1:24];

name=transpose({'ET','SM','T','R','Sens','Soil T',...
'ET','SM','T','R','Sens','Soil T',...
'ET','SM','T','R','Sens','Soil T',...
'ET','SM','T','R','Sens','Soil T'});

b=bar(x,data_forest,'FaceColor','flat');

set(gca,'xTick',(1:1:24));

set(gca,'xticklabel',name);

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Other people have already done this on your previous posts, all you have to do is look at the markdown and do the same thing. Or maybe look in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is just draw 4 times with different colors.

```
data=rand(24,1);
colors={'r','g','b','k'};
figure();
hold on;
for ii=0:3
    bar(ii*6+(1:6),data(ii*6+(1:6)),'FaceColor',colors{ii+1})
end
```